# MySQL - high RAM usage

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, memory

I have VPS with 2GB of RAM running Ubuntu. There are three sites using database on this server - two on WordPress and one on custom script. All of them get max few hits per day.

MySQL always had pretty high RAM usage - usually something around 25%. It's not that much but it looked weird compared to other processes using 1% or 2%.

Today I upgraded OS to Ubuntu 16.04 and now MySQL uses even more RAM - currently it's stuck at 42%.

My question is: is it normal? There are lot of posts about minimizing memory usage by MySQL but I don't know if it's necessary. After all half of RAM is still empty.

[Here is a picture of `htop`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwxYG.png)

Comment: Databases always like to use RAM. Anyway you have plenty available!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not normal.  It is caused by the bug [Excessive memory used in memory/innodb/os0file starting 5.7.8](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80772).

It is tracked in Ubuntu as [Excessive consumption RAM of mysqld daemon in Ubuntu 16.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/akonadi/+bug/1576930), and there is also [a discussion on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/mysql/comments/4gnj93/mysql_5712_ubuntu_1604_ridiculous_memory/).

Answer (score 0):

To explain the difference, you would need to compare the current MySQL configuration with the previous one.

Look at /etc/mysql/my.cnf for the different allocated buffer sizes.  On most configurations, the biggest would be the `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.

Comment: All I have in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` are two `!includedir` directives and in these included directories there are only files with few lines (sometimes even one). I can't find any file with full configuration and option you mentioned.

Comment: You could use `mysqltuner` to consult the current configuration.  You can install it with `sudo apt install mysqltuner`.

Comment: `mysqltuner` looks interesting but it says: 
`Maximum reached memory usage: 196.2M (10.05% of installed RAM. Maximum possible memory usage: 352.4M (18.05% of installed RAM)` which is obviously not true.